# Trying to set a Workbook as a Global variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of macros that process transactions from a transactionWorkbook, through an invoiceWorkbook, then save to archiveWorkbook. I'd like to set up invoiceWorkbook and archiveWorkbook as global variables and have the user select the files in a file_setup macro. Then, I want those variables to be usable in the archive_transaction macro. But even though I have declared them as Public in file_setup, using archiveWorkbook in the later macro throws an "ambiguous name detected: archiveWorkbook" error. Here is the relevant codes snipits:
file_setup macro:

```
Public archiveWorkbook As Workbook
Public invoiceWorkbook As Workbook
Public archiveFilename As String
Public invoiceFilename As String
Sub file_setup()
Set invoiceWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
' open the archive workbook
filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an archive file "
archiveFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set archiveWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(archiveFilename)
```

archive_transaction macro:

```
Sub archive_transaction()

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = archiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

That's where the ambiguous name error occurs. Am I declaring it wrong, setting it wrong?
Many thanks for any and all help

Comment: Do you have anything else named `archiveWorkbook` ?  A module maybe?  Or a sheet codename?

Comment: Simple enough to find if you a search for `archiveWorkbook`. Look for a sub, function or dimmed variable.

Comment: I triple checked that to make sure that there were no other subs, functions, or dims. Just places where I try to use it.